# WHERE date BETWEEN today and next 30 days not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, intervals

I'm having a bit of trouble with pulling records which are due within 30 days. The database I am working with stores the date in a char(10) field in format 103 (dd/mm/yyyy or 10/12/2021). I use a convert function to make this date usable, but when I try to use it with a between query it fails:

```
WHERE 
    CONVERT(Date, SUBSTRING(TDate, 1, 10), 103) 
        BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, 30, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
```

Now I suspect that it fails because `GETDATE()` defaults to format yyyy-mm-dd-time, so the comparison won't work. My question is, how can I convert `GETDATE()` to format 103 to get the correct comparison, or is it a matter of converting my TDate field to something else to get it working?

Comment: Define "it fails". Do you get an error? Warning?

Comment: Another good illustration of why you want to [avoid `BETWEEN` for date/time calculations](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common). This is one of the reasons -- it's not as intuitive as it looks. Not having to repeat the expression for `TDate` has better solutions -- convert the data once and for all, or add a computed column, or use a view on top of the table. All of these will also eliminate the need for others to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: No error @SalmanA, just no results where there should be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression `x BETWEEN a AND b` is same as `x >= a AND x <= b`.

Now `GETDATE() + 30` is always going to be greater than `GETDATE()` so this condition can never be true for **any value** — just like `x >= (y + 30) and x <= y` cannot be true for any x and y.

Then we have another problem, you're comparing a date with datetime. If the date is `2021-12-10` and current datetime is `2021-12-10 12:00 PM` then the comparison will return false when you check date >= datetime. I recommend the following:

```
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, tdate, 103) >= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
AND   CONVERT(DATE, tdate, 103) <= DATEADD(DAY, 29, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) -- the range [0, 29] contains 30 days
```

Comment: This is working perfectly. I can't quite wrap my head around CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE), inherently GETDATE should be DATE. In any case, thank you very much!

Comment: This is for an edge case. GETDATE returns datetime. So if a row has date = `2021-12-10` and you want to include it when current datetime is `2021-12-10 00:00` or `2021-12-10 23:59:59.999` or anything in between then cast is required to get the expected result.

Comment: Thank you. I've also added the following to this, as I noticed it ignored records that we're overdue: OR CONVERT(DATE, TDate, 103) < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)